# Handling deployment of a stateful service?

Tags: design, concurrency, deployment

For fun, I'm developing a multi-player card game. I plan to run it on a single cheap VPS, so deployment would have to kill the process and re-start it with the new code. There is no Load Balancer. I'm okay with deployment causing a few minute outage, but not losing game state. I want to use websockets or real sockets, and not long polling/RESTful APIs.

I am really struggling how to handle a scenario like this:

```js
void yourTurn() { 
  player.tell("Pick a card");
  val cardChosen = player.choose("Yellow 8", "Green 5", ...); // block on player input from socket
  if (isValid(cardChosen)) { ... } 
}
```

What happens if deployment occurs while a thread/coroutine is blocked on the `player.choose`? Or it occurs after the input is accepted, but during validation?

Are there any patterns for dealing with this? Or examples?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You made an effort to narrow this question. It's still pretty broad and leaves a lot of assumptions open to the reader. I'm going to post an answer. Be warned, it's long due to the sort of open ended nature of the question, and may not target exactly what you want. You should find a direct answer to your "what happens?" question, but also a broader look at what it takes to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a moment, forget about sockets, load balancers, all the weeds.

**Focus on the Application Requirements**

You want to be able to deploy an upgrade any time without losing game state. What does that look like to the users?

- You deploy an upgrade.
- Users experience a short and non-baffling delay. Let's say a couple of minutes.
- They can then resume their games without losing any already completed turns.

How do you achieve this?

**First, you need reliable storage and recovery of game state.**

- You need a data store that will not contain invalid game state after being interrupted mid game.

A database with the ACID properties is a simple choice.

When changes are all or nothing, you can insure that the stored game state is always consistent and resumable. Such databases can survive a
'pull the plug' test, where you literally yank the power cable from the wall crashing the server and expect the database to contain a consistent state when it restarts.

If you just don't want to use a database, you can implement a 'good enough for fun projects' solution using single writer access to files.

**Next, A UI that can handle the upgrade scenario**

The UI needs to be...

- Clear about what actions are completed and what actions are just attempted.

  - Ideally the UI doesn't show a card as played until the database confirms that action is recoverable.
  - If the upgrade occurs just as a player plays a card, the UI will pause and show it is waiting for the server, but not show the action as complete.
  - The UI may even time out and say "Come back later to finish the game."
- Able to resume at any point in the game.
- Compatible with the newly upgraded service, or able to reload itself with new compatible code.

**OK Now what about all that plumbing in between?**

What will users experience when you deploy the upgrade? This gets very much into the details of tools and technology. During your few minutes upgrade outage the game service is inaccessible.

This means that the UI's network requests likely encounter one of the following...depending on tools and approach used.

- No response from the service. Looks like a long delay and/or timeout to the user.
- An http 404. (Occurs on some app servers when you make a request while the app is disabled and upgrading).
- A quick TCP level 'Connection Refused' response which occurs on some servers because there is nothing listening on the relevant port.
- A TCP 'Connection Closed' - The server closed connections (sent FIN) during shutdown.

The UI should recognize these situations and let the user know that it may take a few minutes before they can resume their game.

At best the UI might have a fallback process to automatically reconnect to a service instance that is already upgraded. A load balancer or an api gateway could help you with that, but you can do it without that help.

**What about sessions, authentication?**

If you require authentication and you don't want users to have to re-authenticate after an upgrade, your choice of authentication and session keeping methods matters.

If your service uses classic web sessions with session cookies, and loses track of those cookies when you shut down and upgrade the service, users will have to re-authenticate.

If your service uses, for example, encrypted tokens that can still be decrypted after a restart, and can continue a game by retrieving state from the database, your users don't have to re-authenticate as long as the client side UI is still around and still retains the token. (Various OAuth strategies work for this.)

**Ok but what if the service is blocked waiting for user input?**

The simplest answer is, "It's not.". I.E. don't build it that way. That will be more work for you with most toolsets, unless you are building a console style app and running it over ssh or telnet.

A natural way to work with websockets (for example) is to make the service event driven. Some code way down the stack might block listening on a socket, but your app code doesn't care. It just gets called when a message arrives.

When you shut down the service your app-server or framework closes and frees all sockets. Your client app knows how to reconnect.

**No really, I'm worried about that shutdown while blocked issue**
Sure, ok, Websockets with a popular framework or app-server is not enough fun. So you decide to build your own socket listener in a style where it sits in a loop blocking on a timed read() method. It's one of the simplest ways to build a listener.

Your upgrade plan is to take the service down for a few minutes then restart it.

There's no problem with this. Depending on toolset you either build your listener so it is interruptible and shuts down gracefully
closing its socket, or just close the listener's socket while it's blocked waiting. That throws an exception or otherwise unblocks the listener
which then terminates.

The listener then will most likely spend most of its time blocked, waiting for input from clients. When you shut down to upgrade, interrupt
all of your listener threads or close all of their sockets. They will terminate and you have an orderly shutdown.

When you restart the service, it will be ready for client requests and can retrieve game state from the database.

**The Wrap Up**

1. When you shut down the service to upgrade, some users' next action fails because the service is down.

   - But every action either succeeds or fails, no partial actions.
2. The UI recognizes that failure and gives appropriate guidance. Maybe discreetly tries to reconnect every few seconds.
3. When you restart, the user does not need to give credentials again. The UI retrieves game state and is ready for the appropriate player to proceed.

It's possible that a player's last action was completed and not acknowledged in the UI. The player will see that action in the UI after reconnect.

It's not possible that a player's last action was shown in the UI but not completed in the database. Or at least not without a database failure. And that's a different subject.

**Is it really necessary to have those few minutes of downtime?**

No, not really. If you invest the effort you can upgrade the service by starting a new instance on the same or different server.
Then shut down the old instance and let the UI switch to the new instance. This is not the easiest thing to orchestrate and it
requires some discipline in database and client/UI upgrades so you can run an upgrade while people are playing.

If you work at it you can reduce the downtime to a level users may barely notice. Tools like load balancer, CDN, or api gateway
can help manage a seamless upgrade.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I should have mentioned, I would like to connect to the server with telnet (or over SSH so it's not plaintext over the wire). I think that makes it much harder to deal with. I thought about having a "supervisor" process that would almost never need to go down to hold the connection open, but still get stuck in the case where the service (e.g. we're stuck on a method like in my OP) is blocked waiting for user input.

Comment: You can also upgrade the service by starting a new instance, directing new sessions to the new instance, and waiting until everyone playing on the old instance naturally finishes their game before shutting it down.